# Xpath query for data template on list bound to an ObservableCollection<XmlNode>

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

So I am playing with some async stuff in WPF and I am trying to load a combobox with some XML data I pull back from the stack overflow feeds, I am getting the data no problem and I can see that the combo box is populating but I can't seem to get the title of the post. I have tried a few things but the fact of the matter is I just haven't worked with XML data that much and don't know what I am doing.

Here is my data template

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border Background="Azure" Margin="1" Height="24" Width="100">
      <Label Content="{Binding XPath=InnerXml/title}" />
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see I am trying to get "InnerXML/title" - that isn't working and I have tried several other things. Here is where I populate the list

```
private async Task LoadListAsync(string url, int sleep)
    {
        Task<XmlNodeList> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            return GetFeed(url);
        });

        Log("In LoadListAsync before await");

        var list = await task;
        foreach (XmlNode node in list)
        {
            List.Add(node);
        }

        Log("In LoadListAsync, after await"); 
    }
```

Like I said, I can see the foreach loop go and the list populates - I know this cause I can see the borders from the template, I just can't seem to craft and XPath query to get the titles.

Can anyone help with this? Anytime I have done this in the past I have used a XML data source (in blend no less), not an ObserverableCollection, does that have something to do with it?

Thanks.

Here is the XML structure - I can see it in the textbox I bound the SelectedXml to.

```
<id xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">http://stackoverflow.com/q/8872600</id><re:rank scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com\" xmlns:re=\"http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0\">0</re:rank><title type=\"text\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">
Which is faster to use binding using converter or update in a property changed callback?</title>
<category scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wpf/tags\" term=\"wpf\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<category scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wpf/tags\" term=\"binding\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<category scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wpf/tags\" term=\"delegates\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<category scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wpf/tags\" term=\"callback\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<category scheme=\"http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wpf/tags\" term=\"propertychanged\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<author xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"><name>mihajlv</name><uri>http://stackoverflow.com/users/906042</uri></author>
<link rel=\"alternate\" href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872600/which-is-faster-to-use-binding-using-converter-or-update-in-a-property-changed-c\" 
xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" />
<published xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">2012-01-15T19:23:34Z</published>
<updated xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">2012-01-15T19:23:34Z</updated>
<summary type=\"html\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\r\n            &lt;p&gt;I need fast updates, so I was wondering which one is faster and more efficient.&lt;/p&gt;\n\r\n        </summary>
```

Comment: What do the nodes look like in terms of XML-structure?

Comment: That is why I am confused the value of InnerXml looks like this, <id>... <re:rank... then <title> so I thought I could just say InnerXml/title and that it would work.

Comment: So "title" is a tag inside the XML structure? Is it possible for you to give a sample of the node schema so we can make better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`InnerXml` is a meta property of XML nodes, its not something you can access with XPath, if the node has an immediate child element `title` then `XPath=atom:title` should be enough.

Note that there needs to be a [namespace mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752047.aspx) ([without XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx)), and even though the atom namespace is set as the default namespace an `XPath` query needs to qualify the elements.

**Concrete example:**

```
//Contains all 'entry' nodes.
private readonly ObservableCollection<XmlNode> _XmlData = new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>();
public ObservableCollection<XmlNode> XmlData { get { return _XmlData; } }
```

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding XmlData}">
    <Binding.XmlNamespaceManager>
        <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
            <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="atom" Uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
        </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
    </Binding.XmlNamespaceManager>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=atom:title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first try, Xpath=title, but when that didn't work I was sent fishing, Hmm? It clearly does have a title, I know that cause I have looked at the aw XML.

Comment: @Kenn: You should still provide the full XML of a node and see if there [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I know there isn't a binding error - I just set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" and I can see the XML getting set, I even created a property called XmlString and I return SelectedXmlNode.InnerXml and it bind it to a text box which works. The only issue I have is doing an XPath query on it in the combox box datatemplate, what I am doing wrong there I can't figure out.

Comment: @Kenn: And people can't help you without the XML structure. Also obviously the binding that would be broken is the title-binding and not all that other stuff, check for errors.

Comment: I put some sample XML in the main post so you can see the structure of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Kenn: The problem your are having most likely stems from the fact that you need to qualify the element with its namespace, you need to map the atom namespace to a prefix and use that in the `XPath`, see updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Ah duh... I am binding to an ObservableCollecion, of course I can't use an XPath query in it, as far as WPF is concerned its an object just as if I had bound to collection of people, or items or whatever.

I needed to create a converter, I wasn't binding to XML, I was binding to an XmlNode which is an object. Here is the converter.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var node = (XmlNode)value;
         if (node["title"].InnerText == null)
                return "(no title)";
            return node["title"].InnerText;
    }
```

Here is the correct binding.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource XmlNodeToTitleStringConverter}}" />
```

Comment: You are wrong. If you still don't believe me you can try the example i added to my answer.