# Which is faster to use binding using converter or update in a property changed callback?

Tags: wpf, binding, delegates, callback, propertychanged

I need fast updates, so I was wondering which one is faster and more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried any benchmarking on your own?

Comment: I was wondering if anyone knew before I started implementing it.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a severe case of premature optimization. I seriously doubt there will be any noticeable difference between the two. Also, the two really have completely different uses: a converter is used to convert a data type into a more readable/usable form for the ui/user; while property changed events are to notify the UI when a property has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I performed some measurements, and can proclaim, that using a converter in a binding is cheaper than not using it. We're talking about 9% time saving.
Probably, finding / creating a default converter takes more time than taking an instance of a converter from a resource...